# Finite separable extension of a field, free module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, modules

I'm trying to understand proof of following theorem.

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ If $L$ is finite and separable extension of field $K$, $K$ is field of fractions of principal ideal domain $A$ and $B$ is integral closure of $A$ in $L$, then $B$ is free $A$-module of rank $n$, where $n=(L:K)$.

$\textbf{Proof.}$ We know that there exists $b\in B$, such that $L=K(b)$. Then set $\lbrace 1,b,\ldots ,b^{n-1}\rbrace$ forms a basis of $L$ over $K$. So every $c\in B$ can be uniquely expressed as 
$ c = \sum \limits _{i=0}^{n-1} c_{i}b^i$, where $c_{i}\in K,\, i=0,\ldots ,n-1.$ Now so $L$ is separable extension of $K$, thus there exists $n$ $K$-embeddings of $L$ into $a(K)$ (algebraic closure of $K$). Denote this embeddings as $\sigma _{1},\ldots ,\sigma _{n} $. So now we can write $ \sigma _{j}(c)=\sum\limits _{i=0}^{n-1} c_{i}\sigma _{j}(b)^i$, where $j=1,\ldots , n$. Now $\delta = \text{det} (\sigma _{j}(b)^i)=\prod \limits _{1\leqslant k<m\leqslant n} \left(\sigma _{k}(b)-\sigma _{m}(b)\right)\neq 0$. Because $b$ and $c$ are integral over $A$, thus $\sigma _{j}(b),\sigma _{j}(c)$ are integral over $A$, and $\delta$ too. By Cramer's Rule we have
$ c_{i}=\frac {1}{\delta} w_{i}( \sigma _{1}(b),\sigma _{1}(c),\ldots ,\sigma _{n}(b),\sigma _{n}(c)), $ where $w_{i}$ is polynomial with coefficients from $A$. This implies, that $\delta ^2 c_{i}$ is integral over $A$. On the other hand for every $K$-automorphism $\sigma$ of $a(K)$ we have $\lbrace \sigma _{1},\ldots ,\sigma _{n}\rbrace = \lbrace \sigma \sigma _{1},\ldots ,\sigma \sigma _{n}\rbrace$. So $\sigma (\delta)=\pm \delta$, thus $\sigma(\delta ^2)=\delta ^2$, which implies that $\delta ^2\in K$. $A$ is principal ideal domain, so $\delta ^2 c_{i}\in A$. Now we can write 
$ \delta ^2 c = \sum \limits _{i=0}^{n-1} (\delta ^2 c_{i})b^i$
and therefore 
$ \delta ^2 B\subset A+\ldots +Ab^{n-1}\subset B.$
$A$ is principal ideal domain, so every submodule of free $A$-module is free and its rank is not bigger then module's. Now $A+\ldots +Ab^{n-1}$ is free $A$-module of rank $n$, and modules $\delta ^2 B$ and $B$ are isomorphic, so $B$ is free $A$-module of rank $n$.

$\textbf{Questions.}$

$\textbf{1.}$ $\sigma _{j}(b),\sigma _{j}(c)$ are integral over $A$, because they are from $B$ and not from $A$? Why they are from $B$, not from $L\setminus B$?

$\textbf{2.}$ Where does come from polynomial $w_{i}$ and why its coefficients are from $A$?

$\textbf{3.}$ $ \sigma (\delta)=\pm \delta$ just because by $\sigma$ embeddings in definition of $\delta$ can be in different order, which can change sign of product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If write an integral dependence relation for $b$ (resp. $c$) and apply $\sigma_j$ what you get?
2. $\sigma _{j}(c)=\sum\limits _{i=0}^{n-1} c_{i}\sigma _{j}(b)^i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ is a system of equations with the unknowns $c_1,\dots,c_n$. In order to find them one uses the Cramer's rule, so $\delta c_i$ is the determinant of a matrix which has $\sigma_1(c),\dots,\sigma_n(c)$ on the $i$th column and $\sigma_1(b)^j,\dots,\sigma_n(b)^j$ on the $j$th column for $j\ne i$. If expand this determinant by the $i$th column you get sums of products of $\sigma_1(b),\sigma_1(c),\dots$ whose coefficients are in fact integers, so they are in $A$.
3. $\sigma(\delta)$ is also a product of differences $\sigma\sigma_k(b)-\sigma\sigma_m(b)$ and this is some difference $\sigma_i(b)-\sigma_j(b)$, so the product of these differences is the same up to a sign.